# Starting on a tile edge

Tags: castle-ravenloft, dnd-adventure-system

Can't even do the solo game without a question!

Just opened and punched Castle Ravenloft.  Running the intro solo adventure.

1. Place Strahd's Crypt
2. Put your hero anywhere on the tile

I put my Hero right on the edge of the crypt.  After all, the further he can get from Strahd the better!

The turn order is

1. Hero phase
2. Exploration phase
3. Villain phase

So it appears that during my first turn, I have a 4x3 area on Strahd's Crypt to explore.  (There is nothing there).  I can find no rules on placing new tiles during your hero phase so I don't believe my hero can move off the tile edge and needs to wait for the exploration phase to place a tile.

**Is this interpretation correct?**

*I feel like I have to be missing something here.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct.  Tiles are normally placed during the exploration phase.  I haven't found a time when they are placed any other time.

With this scenario, the first turn is, basically, "skip your hero phase", then explore, battle monsters and possibly deal with an encounter.